# Combine .toggle() and form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, toggle

I have a form which I validate using this plug-in : http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

I decided to add fields to this form that would appear if a link is clicked, using `.toggle()`.

Here is the form :

```
<form id="identification" action="Test.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Identification</legend>
        <p>
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" class="required"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" class="required"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">E-mail address</label>
            <input id="email" type="text" name="email" class="required email"/>
        </p>
        <div class="hiddenFields">
            <p>
                <label for="zip">Zip code</label>
                <input id="zip" type="text" name="zip" class="required zip"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="city">City</label>
                <input id="city" type="text" name="city" class="required"/>
            </p>        
        </div>
        <p class="showFields"><a class="toggle" href="#">Click here</a> for more info</p>
    </fieldset> 
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

The `.hiddenFields` div is set as `display: none;` in my CSS.

Here is the validation script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#identification").validate({
        rules: {
                "zip": { digits:true, minlength:5, maxlength:5 }
        }
    });

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        required: "This field is needed.",
        email: "Please enter a valid e-mail address.",
        digits,minlength,maxlength: "Please enter a valid zip code.",
        minlength: "Please enter a valid zip code.",
        maxlength: "Please enter a valid zip code."
    });
});
```

And here is the toggle script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.toggle").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".hiddenFields").toggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Now, everything works fine without the `.hiddenFields` div and without `.toggle()` but when I try to add it, the validation does not work anymore and I don't really understand why.

How can I manage to validate this form when the fields are hidden and when they are not? It currently works in neither of those cases.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: afaik jQuery doesn't have built-in validation. Which plugin are you using?

Comment: Can you put a functional example on jsfiddle.net that reproduces your problem?

Comment: [You can use this as a starting point](http://jsfiddle.net/KhPsw/). That seems to be working. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: No, that's it. What exactly did you modify because this did not work on my setup? Thanks.

Comment: I removed the strange 'digits,minlength' bit in the hash that was causing a syntax error. I had assumed it was a copy/paste error and didn't realise that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here it is on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2nj/).

You have a rogue `digits,minlength,` causing a syntax error:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
   required: "This field is needed.",
   email: "Please enter a valid e-mail address.",
   digits,minlength,maxlength: "Please enter a valid zip code.",
   minlength: "Please enter a valid zip code.",
   maxlength: "Please enter a valid zip code."
});
```

You've also got `maxlength` in there twice.

Changing it to this will fix it:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
   required: "This field is needed.",
   email: "Please enter a valid e-mail address.",
   minlength: "Please enter a valid zip code.",
   maxlength: "Please enter a valid zip code."
});
```

Comment: It definitely was a copy/paste error, I didn't even notice it. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @morgi I don't know which browser you use but if you load the Developer Tools in Chrome or IE (press F12 to show) or the [Firebug  extension](http://http://getfirebug.com) in Firefox (press F12 to show, too) and see the Console tab, you can inspect any JavaScript errors that occur.